# I've created a modal component in Vue.js that doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've created a modal component in Vue JS. It has to display all the names typed in the form. It doesn't work. What I can do to solve this problem? I'm new in Vue JS. Also I can't use shorthands. Do you know why? PLease help me. Thank you in advance.
This is my code:

```
<template>
  <div class="template_class">
  <div>
  <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>

  <!-- Main UI -->
  <div class="mt-3 mb-3">
    Submitted Names:
    <ul>
      <li v-for="n in names">{{n}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal Component -->
  <b-modal id="modal1" title="Submit your name" @ok="submit" @shown="clearName">

    <form @submit.stop.prevent="submit">
      <b-form-input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" v-model="name"></b-form-input>
    </form>

  </b-modal>
</div>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: {
    name: '',
    names: []
  },
  methods: {
    clearName() {
        this.name = '';
      },
      submit(e) {
        if (!this.name) {
          alert('Please enter your name');
          return e.cancel();
        }

        this.names.push(this.name);
        this.name = '';
      }
  }
}

</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Please be more clear than "doesn't work" about what you expect it to do that it is not doing. Also helpful to mention that you're using [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/).

Comment: It has to display all the names typed on form. But it doesen't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected for me. **Edit** I removed the `@shown` binding from the modal, as it seems to introduce some bugginess.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'Pigman',
    names: []
  },
  methods: {
    clearName() {
      this.name = "";
    },
    submit(e) {
      if (!this.name) {
        alert('Please enter your name');
        return e.cancel();
      }

      this.names.push(this.name);
      this.clearName();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add this to <head> -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@next/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/tether@latest/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="template_class">
  <div>
    <b-btn v-b-modal.modal1>Launch demo modal</b-btn>
    Current name: {{name}}

    <!-- Main UI -->
    <div class="mt-3 mb-3">
      Submitted Names:
      <ul>
        <li v-for="n in names">{{n}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Component -->
    <b-modal id="modal1" title="Submit your name" @ok="submit">

      <form @submit.stop.prevent="submit">
        <b-form-input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" v-model="name"></b-form-input>
      </form>

    </b-modal>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me, it doesen't display the submited names. Can you help me? Please. :(

Comment: I opened the console and this is what i've got: [Vue warn]: Property or method "names" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

Comment: What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 and Google Chrome.

Comment: Interesting: on Safari (Mac), the modal comes up with the lat value entered for name, despite the variable `name` being reset. I think there is a bug in Bootstrap-Vue.

Comment: @CatalinAvasiloaie I have updated my answer. The `@shown` binding was making things behave weird, so try running without it.

Comment: It doesen't work. I think i'm doing something wrong. Can you please tell me what i have to do step by step? I'm a real noob in Vue JS.

Comment: When you run this snippet here, does it work for you?

Comment: Here yes. It works good. But when I add it to my project, it doesn't. I think I'm doing something wrong when I add it.

Comment: When I add this code, all the content from my page dissapear.

Comment: When I add just HTML code, all is ok. Modal doesn't work, but at least it appear in my page. What can I do to make it functional?

Comment: There are too many possibilities for me to diagnose it without seeing your code. Could be duplicate `id` values. Could be importing the same libraries multiple times, or wrong versions. Can you start with just the code here and add pieces of your code to it until it breaks? Or can you put together a fiddle that shows the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make any sense to me, this is a great reusable example from the vue homepage https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html

This code is directly copied from the example, i only cite it as single file component:

```
<template>
  <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name: 'modal'
}
</script>

<style>
.modal-mask {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9998;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: table;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .33);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.modal-header h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #42b983;
}

.modal-body {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.modal-default-button {
  float: right;
}

/*
 * The following styles are auto-applied to elements with
 * transition="modal" when their visibility is toggled
 * by Vue.js.
 *
 * You can easily play with the modal transition by editing
 * these styles.
 */

.modal-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-enter .modal-container,
.modal-leave-active .modal-container {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: In this fiddle it works https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/mwLbw11k/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=mwLbw11k